# convert Zip3 and zip5 level shapefiles to x-y coordinates

Tags: r, gis, microstrategy

I am not sure how to start this, as my GIS playing in R has been to plot things using ggplot2 and other packages using latlong coordinates. What I need to do now, is to use a visualization component in Microstrategy that uses a shapefile in the form of an HTML file containing x-y coordinates for the plot (ie. top left is 0,0). An example of a state level file is:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>untitled</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<IMG SRC="" USEMAP="#myMap" WIDTH="812" HEIGHT="713" BORDER="0" />
<MAP NAME="myMap">
<AREA SHAPE="POLY" HREF="#" ALT="Texas" COORDS="299,363,299,360,....." />
</MAP></BODY></HTML>
```

The points listed in 'coords' are the X and Y points with respect to a 812 by 713 'image' that is plotted and colored on the fly.

I have shp, shx, dbf files for Zip3 and Zip5 from http://www.vdstech.com/usa-data.aspx but am unsure of where to even start the conversion! I don't mind doing the grunt work of formatting the HTML file by hand, it is the X-Y conversion that I am stuck at (rusty, not touched GIS for quite a while):

The following code imports the shapefile into R

```
library(rgdal)
zip3 <- readOGR(dsn = '/Users/adempsey/Downloads/zip3'), layer = 'zip3')
```

After which I am stuck and currently hunting for tutorial of how to extract zip3 + x-y coordinates into a dataframe that I can then use to create my final file with

update 2

using the following, I ca convert to a data frame, but I am unable to pull across the associated zip3 code, which appeared to be stored in the associated dbf file

```
Row long      lat order  hole piece group id
1 -151.0604 70.41873     1 FALSE     1   0.1  0
2 -150.7620 70.49722     2 FALSE     1   0.1  0
```

Yes, this is beyond my current rusty R

update3
This code dumps the zip codes into a data frame
    zip3.codes <- as.data.frame(zip3) 
Which should be combinable with something like
    zip3.df <- fortify(zip3@polygons[[1000]])
Where the 1000 would be replaced with all the rows zip3.codes associated with a particular zip3

Comment: what about `fortify` from the `ggplot2` package?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that function. I am still poking around with the  zip3 variable and its structure

Comment: fortify will convert from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to a `data.frame` for plotting with `ggplot2`.

Comment: Okay, I have found that the zip3 codes are in the DBF file, but I cant work out how to associate them with the shp file and thus get them into my data frame.

Comment: Yes, but these were accessed by `readOGR` and the data available within R.

Comment: How do I get to them? I have tried zip3@ZIPC... I can't figure out the 'slot' that holds the zip name and it does not appear in the resulting data frame from fortify

Comment: `as.data.frame(zip3)` or `zip3@data`.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24484/discussion-between-mnel-and-andrew-dempsey)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fastshp](http://rforge.net/fastshp) package to load the data:

```
 install.packages("fastshp",,"http://rforge.net")
 library(fastshp)
 s <- read.shp("zip5.shp", format="polygon")
```

`s` is now a list of all ZIP shapes. You're interested in the `x` and `y` components
- for example to plot the first ZIP simply use something like

```
 plot(s[[1]]$x, s[[1]]$y, asp=1.25)
 polygon(s[[1]]$x, s[[1]]$y, col="#eeeeee")
```

To match the names, use `read.dbf` from `foreign`:

```
 library(foreign)
 d <- read.dbf("zip5.dbf", as.is=TRUE)
 names(s) <- d$ZIP5
```

See `?read.shp` for more details on the available formats. The "polygon" one uses `NA` to separate individual polygons, "list" uses indexing to give you the parts.

BTW the dataset is somewhat dubious, you may want to look into TIGER/Line census ZCTA5 data (most recent is 2010).